# is there a design pattern that isolate 'methods' from member?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

basically, i want to have something like:
    class DataProcessor{
    };

however, in the future, i will need to pass DataProcessor's instance to some other functions, because DataProcessor contains some crucial data.

what I got in mind is to separate the members from methods:

```
class DataProcessorCore{};
class DataProcessor : public DataProcessorCore    {};
```

Is this a common way to do this job? or there is some patterns out there that I can fit my ideas into?

thanks a lot

Comment: I guess that by "members" you mean "properties", right?

Comment: IMHO, methods are members too...

Comment: If you don't want methods and members in the same place, don't use objects

Comment: I don't understand. Which object contains the member variables? DataProcessor or DataProcessorCore?

Comment: Opinion doesn't enter into it. In the C++ standard, data members and member functions are both kinds of class member. 9.2/1: "Members of a class are data members, member functions, nested types, and enumerators".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Strategy Pattern is the one you are looking for. This would give you the oppurtunity to change the methods working on your data at runtime.

[wiki: strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure this is a pattern, I would just use an interface.

```
class DataProcessorCore {
   public virtual void doProcessing() = 0;

   // Any other virtual methods, but no implementation
};

class DataProcessor : public DataProcessorCore {
   // implement the methods
};
```

Now anything that just needs the functionality of DataProcessor should take the interface class instead of the concrete class.  If I understand you correctly, then this achieves separating the methods from the methods.

Comment: "Interface" *is* a pattern ;-)

Comment: I guess it's the old argument about whether it's a pattern, idiom or language feature (e.g. visitor in C++ vs. double dispatch in CLOS).  But I see your point!

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it's C# question and extension methods came into my mind, but when I spotted this is C++ I tryed to find analogy and, as I understand, the analogy is

> Argument dependent name (Koenig)
>   lookup

Reference:

[Extension Methods - A Polished C++ Feature](http://vivekragunathan.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!753E720D857C98F6!368.entry)

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see *why* you want other function to see an object with data and no methods. What is the problem in passing the usual kind of object, which has both?

Second, what should that function see? An object with all-public member variables? Or just one with private member variables and *fewer* accessor/mutator methods than DataProcessorCore?

A relatively common idiom in C++ is to put as many methods as possible *outside* the object.

So your solution could be something like this:

```
class DataProcessor {
   // Fill in only the basics. Member variables and a small set of "core" functions to access/modify them.
};

void ComplexOperation(DataProcessor& proc) { ...}
float AnotherOperation(DataProcessor& proc, int i) { ...}
```

And then eliminate `DataProcessorCore` entirely. You don't need it, because you have the object containing the data (and, I'd assume, a small set of core functions), and all the more extensive functionality can be implemented as free functions instead of in a dereived class.

The standard library uses this technique extensively. Think of `std::sort` which is not a member of individual container classes, but a free function that can be called *on* a container.

Answer (score 0):

An Interface that offers only getters()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want, but maybe the Decorator pattern is one to have a look at.

> The Decorator Pattern attaches
>   additional functionality to an object
>   dynamically. Decorators provide a
>   flexible alternative to subclassing
>   for extending functionality.

[Wiki : Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can achieve this by combining inheritence and abstraction patterns

```
interface Operations {
  public void printValue();
}

public class Data {

  private String value;

  protected void loadValues() {
   this.value = "somevalue";
  }

  protected String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

public class DataProvider extends Data implements Operations {
  public Operate() {
    super.load();
  }

  public void printValue() {
    System.out.println("Value is "+getValue());
  }
}

public class Consumer {
  public static void main() {
    Operations operate = (Operations) new DataProvider();
    operate.printValue();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Holger Says the pattern that will fit is the Strategy, separating the logic of processing the data from the data-structure itself. More insight on what they try to do would be useful, patterns emerges, they are not applied.